# TeamCity/Mercurial - broken patch

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

I've set up TeamCity (v6.5.5 - build 18087) to build an ASP.NET project from Mercurial. Twice in 56 build now I have got the error below, and the only common denominator I can see is that these changesets had files added to them.

If I clear the server's mercurial cache I get rif of the problem until next time, but that's not a great solution.

I've seen posts from people with similar problems, but haven't found a solution from reading them.

Would be thankful if someone can point me in the right direction here.

From TeamCity build log:

```
[20:54:21]: Patch is broken, can be found in file: C:\BuildAgent\temp\cache\temp547491181020464280patch_64 
[20:54:21]: Failed to build patch for build #56 {build id=64}, VCS root: mercurial: http://server:8000 {instance id=1, parent id=2}, due to error: 'cmd /c hg cat -o C:\TeamCity\temp\mercurial9111169551826812670catresult\%p -r 75f205de9192 website\MasterPage.master website\MasterPage.master.designer.cs website\OurProject.csproj website\Login.aspx website\Login.aspx.designer.cs website\apage.aspx website\apage.aspx.designer.cs website\anotherpage.aspx website\anotherpage.aspx.designer.cs website\thirdpage.aspx website\thirdpage.aspx.designer.cs' command failed. stderr: abort: data/website/thirdpage.aspx.i@2b64b5d6eb86: no match found! 

jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl$1: Server was not able to build correct patch, most likely due to VCS errors, will try again. at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl.throwError(PatchDownloaderImpl.java:113) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl.checkPatch(PatchDownloaderImpl.java:103) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl.copyPatchAndCheck(PatchDownloaderImpl.java:64)...
```

Comment: if you dont get good answers, consider asking this on the jetBrains TeamCity forum: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/teamcity